# android system animation duration

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-kernel

I just wonder how long is the android **system animation** (the animation for Activity A switch to Activity B )duration , and how can I measure this time . Should I use some tools or use log in the code?

Answer (score 4):

The system animation time between activities or fragment is defined by (in xml):

```
@android:integer/config_activityShortDur
@android:integer/config_activityDefaultDur
```

or (in Java):

```
android.R.integer.config_activityShortDur
android.R.integer.config_activityDefaultDur
```

From the sources:

```
<!-- The duration (in milliseconds) of a short animation. -->
<integer name="config_shortAnimTime">200</integer>

<!-- The duration (in milliseconds) of a medium-length animation. -->
<integer name="config_mediumAnimTime">400</integer>

<!-- The duration (in milliseconds) of a long animation. -->
<integer name="config_longAnimTime">500</integer>

<!-- The duration (in milliseconds) of the activity open/close and fragment open/close animations. -->
<integer name="config_activityShortDur">150</integer>
<integer name="config_activityDefaultDur">220</integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set animation duration in xml file add the line

```
   android:duration="yourtime"
```

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="200" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="200" />
```

you can call like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: if i do not set the animation ,what is the duration by default in android OS?

Comment: without animation why you want to set duration between activities?

Comment: becasue the android OS set the system animation by default

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the animation duration in Android under Settings -> Developer Options. It's user preference which means you can't change it.
[image]